# How to send new mail with the given date using PHP with office365 API

Tags: php, api, office365api

I want to send new mail with the given date (Previous date) using PHP with the office 365 API. How to do that?

Comment: Are you looking to set the sent timestamp for the mail?  I believe that is set by the service and not something you can set using the APIs.

Comment: Yes ,but i have to set timestamp for sending the mail.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Venkat is right: you can't do that. The server will always stamp the sent date/time to the current date and time. What is your scenario?

Comment: My scenario: Today date is 17-01-2015 but I want to the sent mail to this date 16-01-2015 not to the current date.

Comment: The API doesn't support this. You might consider posting this as a suggestion on http://officespdev.uservoice.com/ and include *why* you want to do this.